Manjaro zsh python-argcomplete error after update
After recently updating my system after a while I noticed my zsh terminal wasn't working properly. When I try tab completing it gave
(eval):1: _python-argcomplete: function definition file not found
(eval):1: _python-argcomplete: function definition file not found
(eval):1: _python-argcomplete: function definition file not found

I do not have any extra configuration, only the default manjaro zsh configs. My $fpath and $FPATH variables seem to be working as expected.

Fix:
activate-global-python-argcomplete

More details
I found that in manjaro zsh config /usr/share/zsh/manjaro-zsh-config, this line causes the problem:
compinit -d

If the above fix does not help, try commenting out this line or removing ~/.zcompdump.
The fix originated from this stackoverflow answer.

Note this can work either for specific user with activate-global-python-argcomplete --user or system-wide with sudo activate-global-python-argcomplete

In my case, I was missing a package:
sudo apt install python3-argcomplete

After installing it started working fine.
